# How to clone, modify (increment some elements) before appending using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that contains multiple elements inside it, what I need is to clone the element, but on every "new" element, I need to increment an element (the object number -see my script please-)

In the script I'm adding I need (every time I click on the button) to have : Hello#1 (by default it's the first one) but the first click make : Hello#2 (and keep on top Hello#1) second click = Hello#1 Hello#2 Hello#3 ... We need to keep the oldest hellos and show the first one.

```js
var count = 1;
$(".button").click(function(){    
   count += 1;
    num = parseInt($(".object span").text());
    $(".object span").text(count);
    
   var cont = $(".container"),
   div = cont.find(".object").eq(0).clone();    
   cont.append(div);
});
```

```css
.object{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button">
create object
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="object">
  <p>
  

     hello#<span>1</span>
    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change a little:

```js
var count = 1;
$(".button").click(function() {
  count += 1;
  num = parseInt($(".object span").text());


  var cont = $(".container"),
    div = cont.find(".object").eq(0).clone();
  div.find('span').text(count); // <------here you have to put the count
  cont.append(div);
});
```

```css
.object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button">
  create object
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="object">
    <p>
      hello#<span>1</span>
    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```

and if you want to simplify this more use this:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var idx = ++$('.object').length; // check for length and increment it with ++
  var cont = $(".container"),
      div = cont.find(".object").eq(0).clone();
  div.find('span').text(idx); // <------here you have to put the count
  cont.append(div);
});
```

```css
.object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button">
  create object
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="object">
    <p>
      hello#<span>1</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function, this is more modular and you can use it to update the count if you remove one of the elements

```js
function updateCount() {
  $(".object").each(function(i,v) {
    $(this).find("span").text(i+1);
  });
}
$(".button").click(function() {
  num = parseInt($(".object span").text());
  var cont = $(".container"),
  div = cont.find(".object").eq(0).clone();
  cont.append(div);

  updateCount();
});
```

```css
.object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button">
  create object
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="object">
    <p>
      hello#<span>1</span>
    </p>
  </div>


</div>
```